# How to make nodeos save only last "n" blocks?

Tags: nodeos

I am running EOS node and synced using latest snapshot from [eosnode.tools](https://eosnode.tools/snapshots). I want to make my node save only latest 1 000 000 blocks. What should I do achieve this? May be there is a specific argument that I have to pass to `nodeos`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not implemented in the nodeos app. You can use logrotate to truncate the log daily and keep 5 days of history but this is not integrated to nodeos.

It is an operating system tool which is usually used for log files.

With nodeos you want to be able to query the server to fetch blocks and this is not the right way to implement the feature you want. Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: Got it!Thank you for your answer!